# column and column = :variable does not working in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate

> `SELECT fr1 FROM Friend fr1 where fr1.userIdOne AND fr1.userIdTwo IN (:list) 
>   why operator 'AND' does not work for this in hql?`

Gives me [this](http://pastebin.com/Gah7j8Zg) error. Could someone shed a bit of light on this? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you take some time to identate your code and then you ask for help?

Comment: SELECT b FROM backEnd.model.BusinessProfile b WHERE b.idBusiness IN(SELECT ub.idBusiness FROM backEnd.model.UserBusiness ub where ub.userId IN (SELECT (fr1.userIdOne + fr1.userIdTwo - 4) FROM backEnd.model.Friend fr1 where fr1.userIdOne AND fr1.userIdTwo IN (SELECT (fr.userIdOne + fr.userIdTwo - 4) FROM backEnd.model.Friend fr where fr.userIdOne = 4 OR fr.userIdTwo = 4)))
This is my code. HQL

Comment: :list is equals subquery

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `AND` keyword between logical statements. Your query should be as follows:
`SELECT fr1 FROM Friend fr1 where fr1.userIdOne IN (:list) AND fr1.userIdTwo IN (:list)`

Comment: But what to do when - :list is equals subquery?

Comment: In this case I think you must copy the subquery.